# SQL code in an update query

Tags: sql, database, vba, ms-access

Once again Im stuck on the same database. This time Im creating an update query that removes 1 of each part in a table when a button is pressed. But when a part is already at 0 it goes to -1. How can I stop this from happening?

I used SQL to achieve this,

```
UPDATE [ASM-00065 WIP] 
SET [ASM-00065 WIP].[Current Stock] = [ASM-00065 WIP]![Current Stock]-1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be understanding your question incorrectly, but do you want to update all rows in that  table for that column, and subtract 1 from them? In that case you can use:

```
UPDATE [ASM-00065 WIP] 
SET [ASM-00065 WIP].[Current Stock] = [ASM-00065 WIP]![Current Stock]-1 
WHERE [ASM-00065 WIP].[Current Stock] > 0
```

Comment: Can I create another part which enables me to take out two of one thing in that table but still take out 1 of everything else?

Comment: You can use syntax similar to the one provided by bluefeet: UPDATE [ASM-00065 WIP] 
SET [Current Stock] 
   = IIF(Condition for subtracting 2 AND [Current Stock]>1, [Current Stock] - 2, IIF([Current Stock]>0, [Current Stock]-1, [Current Stock]));

Comment: Is there any way i can create the SQL code or even use VBA to inform the user that some of the records in the table = 0 when they press the button. I want to create it so they cannot remove any data from the table if one or more records = 0

Comment: The previous SQL code doesnt solve my problem, In my database I have 'Kits' and when a 'Kit' is removed one of each part that makes up the kit is also removed. For example, ASM-00065 consists of 6 parts. But one of these parts has two pieces. So i want to remove 2 of, say, MEC-00218 but still remove one of everything else. How can this be done?

Comment: Instead of informing the user that there are zero records, I would simply not display them to the user, if the record count is zero. For the second problem, it would be useful if you wrote a stored proc which takes the part numbers for the kit, and deletes the parts individually from the table.

Comment: I would rather the user be informed about the stock. I need some sort of code to help me with that. The guy below says to write it on the "onclick" event but i have no idea where to start. Proc?

Comment: He means the button onClick event in vba. Something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090379/button-click-event-in-vb

Answer (score 1):

Is MS-Access you can use [`IIF()`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/iif-function-HA001228853.aspx)

```
UPDATE [ASM-00065 WIP] 
SET [Current Stock] 
   = IIF([Current Stock]>0, [Current Stock]-1, [Current Stock]);
```

Comment: Is there any way i can create the SQL code or even use VBA to inform the user that some of the records in the table = 0 when they press the button. I want to create it so they cannot remove any data from the table if one or more records = 0

Comment: @MichaelMcWilliams you would need to use VBA to notify them `OnClick` event that there are records that meet you condition. You could use a `MsgBox` to display the note.

Comment: Im going to have a stab at it here using VBA. If i have any problems ill post them on here

Comment: @MichaelMcWilliams if you have problems, then post a new question. good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a condition to filter the rows that you will update:

```
UPDATE [ASM-00065 WIP] SET [ASM-00065 WIP].[Current Stock] = [ASM-00065 WIP]![Current Stock]-1 WHERE [ASM-00065 WIP]![Current Stock] > 0;
```